# Write a complex loop in pythonic way

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following Code

```
import numpy as np
from readers import readerXYZ
import glob 
folder=r'N:\FolderXYZ/*'
D_list=[]
ctr=0

for name in glob.glob (folder):

    Zdata = readerXYZ(name, output_matrix=True) 

    #I Need this counter of the NaNs for future computations
    ctr=ctr+np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(Zdata))    
    a=list(Zdata.shape)
    D_list.append(a)
```

The program reads from different files stored in the Folder called "FolderXYZ", this is done with an external program called readerXYZ, what I want to store in the lis D_list is the dimensions of each Zdata Matrix, and at the same time count how many NaNs are in total.
This code works fine but takes so Long, how can I improve it?
thank you

Comment: Optimization should be posted on code review. You should start by profiling the code to identify which steps are costly. I recommend cProfile. I believe the slow part is probably in the `readerXYZ` function...

Comment: It might be possible to get the dimensions and count NaN elements without loading the entire matrix into memory. But that would depend on the format of the files.

Answer (score 0):

If time is your concern. You can consider processing the list in parallel. Here is a reference for multiprocessing
[Python how to parallelize loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649163/python-how-to-parallelize-loops)